# Cordova/Ionic2 Native Maps: touching div ontop of map "bleeds through"

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, android-maps-v2

I have a div overtop of my map as a menu. When I touch the map, it "bleeds through" and acts as if I touched the map itself. I can't seem to find a map property to fix this. I also can't interact with the divs that are on top. It's like the map's position is visible at `zIndex: 0` but it occupies every possible index.

Here is my code:

TS/JS

```
this.map = new GoogleMap('map', {
      'backgroundColor': 'white',
      'controls': {
        'compass': false,
        'myLocationButton': false,
        'indoorPicker': false,
        'zoom': false
      },
      'gestures': {
        'scroll': true,
        'tilt': true,
        'rotate': true,
        'zoom': true
      },
      'camera': {
        'latLng': location,
        'tilt': 30,
        'zoom': 15,
        'bearing': 50
      }
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

CSS

```
#test
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}
#map
{
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set your map to not be clickable when you have an element above it ([source](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/Map#mapsetclickable)):

```
//Before showing your overlaying div:
map.setClickable(false);
```

Comment: What if I want the div it to always be on the screen? Where it is just partially covering the screen

Answer (score 0):

This is documented some [in the Cordova plugin documentation](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/tree/master/v1.4.0/class/Map#how-does-the-plugin-work).

To make your div clickable, put it inside of the map element. The plugin will watch the div and ensure that it is clickable.

One thing I've noticed, though, is that if you are dynamically showing or hiding the div, the plugin doesn't always pick it up, and the clicks go straight through to the map. I've been able to get around this by calling:

```
this.map.refreshLayout();
```

whenever I show/hide the overlay div. [Documentation for refreshLayout](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v1.4.0/class/Map/refreshLayout/README.md).

Alternatively, you can do as Schlaus recommended and call `map.setClickable(false)`, but it doesn't seem like that will work for you in your case since you still want the map to be clickable.